# Where to connect c wire for thermostat to hydrostat 3250-plus

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

trying to add c wire for nest learning thermostat but there is no connection on the heater. Where can I connect?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Could you provide more information about the controller box on the left side of the schematic? Model number, or perhaps a photo of the one installed in your system?